# Don't match leading whitespace

Tags: regex

For a string in this format `--> Welcome to Stack Overflow<http://stackoverflow.com>`, I have the expression `(.*?)<(.*?)>` which current matches `--> Welcome to Stack Overflow` and `http://stackoverflow.com`

However, I'd like it to only match `Welcome to Stack Overflow` and `http://stackoverflow.com`, by not including any content prior to, and including the whitespace.

Same applies for `Take the tour<http://stackoverflow.com/tour> |Need help?<http://stackoverflow.com/help>` which should match `Take the tour`, `http://stackoverflow.com/tour`, `|Need help?` and `http://stackoverflow.com/help`

I've tried various approaches using `^\s` and `^\S` but neither is working. How can I match my expectations?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Objective-C, but regex like this isn't language specific. I'm quite certain the answer would be in the same in Java, C#, Swift or JavaScript to name a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\S*\s*` at the beginning of the regexp. This will match the first non-whitespace followed by whitespace, and not include them in the capture group.

```
\S*\s*(.*?)<(.*?)>
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yR2xW7/3)

Comment: That fulfils the second match, but not the first. https://regex101.com/r/yR2xW7/2

Comment: So you also want to skip the first non-whitespace before the first whitespace, to get rid of `-->` at the beginning?

Comment: If possible. I realise now that might be overcomplicating it a bit.